# How to get the Dirac representation of a general quantum gate?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, matrix-representation, linear-algebra

writing a matrix from bra-ket notations is easier. Going back is like finding prime factors. How to get the bra-ket form of all basic quantum gates in their matrix form in general?

Answer (score 3):

If a matrix $A$ has components $A_{ij}$, then you can represent it using bra-ket notation as $\sum_{ij} A_{ij} |i\rangle\!\langle j|$.